# postgreSQL-12: Is there a way to enable FIFO to limit database table storage capacity?

Tags: thingsboard, postgresql-12

I have a ThingsBoard PE setup using AWS EC2 instance, with postgreSQL-12 as the database.

There is a table `ts_kv_2020_10` which stores all telemetry data for the month of October.

[image: ts_kv_2020_10]

Is there a way I can enable FIFO on this `ts_kv_2020_10` table to keep storage at a fixed capacity of example 1GB? (i.e. When limit is reached, data that was first stored onto the table will automatically be replaced by the lastest incoming data.)

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no built-in feature in Postgres for that.

You will either need to roll your own (e.g. using triggers) or use [partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE) to get rid of an entire month once it's not needed any longer.